# Problems creating a debdiff

Tags: development, patch

I'm following [this](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/PackagingGuide/Howtos/Debdiff) guide to create a debdiff for a package I'm patching. Everything goes fine until step number 8 and I attempt to create the debdiff after committing the changes. The package in question is Zim, pulled form Launchpad using

```
bzr branch lp:zim
```

and according to this guide I should execute the following command to create the debdiff:

```
debdiff zim_0.49.dsc zim_0.49ubuntu1.dsc > zim_0.49ubuntu1.debdiff
```

however, when I actually try to execute this command, I get the following error:

```
debdiff: fatal error at line 314:
Can't read file: zim_0.49.dsc
```

Upon inspection of the directory in which the files created from `debuild -S` (step 6) are deposited, I find

```
zim_0.49ubuntu1_source.changes
zim_0.49ubuntu1.dsc           
zim_0.49ubuntu1.tar.gz
zim_0.49ubuntu1_source.build
```

but no sign of `zim_0.49.dsc`. I could probably create one by debuilding the package as soon as I check out the code, before starting work, but that would add an extraneous entry in the `changelog`.

Is there a step missing from the guide that creates `zim_0.49.dsc` or is the file itself missing from the source?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, if you are using bzr, then there is no need to muck about with debdiff.  Just commit your change, then push to a personal branch on lp and propose that it be merged.

If you really want a debdiff, then you need the previous version of the package to diff against.  Fetch it with apt-get source.